# How to use static build of Qt to create a statically-linked release for Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7-x64, qt5.3

How am I supposed to use my static build of Qt in my project directory?  There seems to be a missing step in the [official documentation](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows) between building a static version of Qt and then building a statically-linked version of your app with that static version of Qt.

Comment: What exactly is missing? You configure with `-static` and in your .pro you add `CONFIG+=static`

Comment: @cen You're wrong. The CONFIG+=static is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no explicit step, since all you need to do is use that statically-compiled Qt to build your project. That's all. From the command line, simply invoke the statically-compiled Qt's `qmake` and your project will statically link to Qt. From Qt Creator, add the statically-compiled Qt's kit to your project's configurations and build for it.

Of course you must first add that Qt version to Qt Creator, and add it to a new kit. Note that as far as both Qt and Qt Creator is concerned, a "Qt version" is a synonym for *a build of Qt*. So if you have 4 different builds of Qt 5.3.1 (say dynamic multithreaded, dynamic single threaded, static multithreaded, and static), they are considered different Qt versions. Because a "Qt version", as used throughout, has nothing whatsoever to do with the *sources* of Qt, just with *a build* of Qt. If all you do is download a source package of Qt, you have no Qt versions yet :)